# Regex (in Javascript) Alpha plus spaces, up to 20 characters, no special characters, must be unique

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, indicative

I am using the great [Indicative](https://indicative.adonisjs.com/guides/master/introduction) library and using one of their regex methods.

```
import { validations } from 'indicative/validator'
 
const rules = {
  username: [
    validations.regex(['^[a-z]+'])
  ]
}
 
// or
const rules = {
  username: [
    validations.regex([new RegExp('^  [a-z]+')])
  ]
}
```

In my case I'm trying to validate vs. the following:

- Alpha only but can allow for spaces
- Up to 20 characters No special characters
- Must be a unique value If user enters existing value *

This is what I created;

```
validations.regex(["/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]){1,20}(?=.*[`~,.<>;':"\/\[\]\|{}()=_+-])\s$/"])
```

Is there any place where you can learn step by step?

What I mean suppose you would take the bullets above and guide you into writing them?

Thanks!

Update:
This is what I meant by a unique value:

```
foo bar
foo bar /* Not unique */
```

Comment: `Must be a unique value If user enters existing value`: Can you clarify this with few examples

Comment: I updated to what I meant.

Comment: For uniqueness you must compare the value with your users list (from database or where you have that list). That is not a job for regex.

Comment: Try this regex for validation: `^[a-zA-Z ]+$` (note the space inside the character class).

Comment: Thanks @Poul what about the min, max value?

Comment: Now I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[a-zA-Z ]{1,20}+$//: Nothing to repeat
`

Comment: Just delete the plus sign! Then it should be perfect. `+` means: one or more of the preceeding, here you specify: 1 to 20, the error says you can't do both.